# Spring Boot Heroku very slow deployment

Tags: spring, spring-boot, heroku, deployment, heroku-cli

I'm wondering what else I can do to reduce deploying time of Java app in Heroku. Now it take approximately 30min sometimes even longer. I am trying with both .jar and .war archives and both via heroku cli and as a maven plugin. It does not matter what I choose, deploy time remains similar. App is not such heavy, for .jar it is about 70MB, for war 160MB (because for maven plugin it takes all dependencies additionaly).

this is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>pl.jawegiel</groupId>
    <artifactId>myservlet2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jetty-version>9.4.10.v20180503</jetty-version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <full-artifact-name>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</full-artifact-name>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- Servlet API -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zaxxer/HikariCP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0-M7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.12</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.14</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0.Alpha5</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>pl.jawegiel.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <appName>jawegiel-web</appName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

What else do you need to investigate the issue? I will mark your answer as best one if it helps!

Comment: That seems like a very long time. Please [edit] your question and show us your build logs.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out my internet provider slows down my connection down to 30kb/s when upload is to big.